# how to access parameters from url in cakephp 2.9.7

Tags: cakephp

My Cakephp URL looks like this.I want to access the parameter table_name

```
http://cakephp-2.9.7/fetchPages/index/table_name:House_Price
```

What i have Tried:

```
$table_name = $this->request->query('table_name');
$table_name = $this->request->data('table_name');
$table_name = $this->request->query['table_name'];
$table_name = $this->request->getQuery('table_name');
```

Nothing is working fine with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are [Named Parameters](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#named-parameters)

You have to use it like this

```
$this->request['named']['table_name'] 

$this->request->params['named']['table_name']

$this->params['named']['table_name']

$this->passedArgs['table_name']
```

Comment: Thank You so much.This helped me a lot